# How can I use WordPress' "the_title" filter just for the main title inside the Post Type?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I'm trying to change the title in WordPress:

```
function change_title_func($title) {
  if( in_the_loop() && !is_archive() ) { // Avoiding Menu Items
     return $title.'<span class="cls"></span>';
  }
}
add_filter('the_title', change_title_func(), 10, 2);
```

but the anchor's title attribute also gets changed and I don't want that. Example:

```
<a href="..." title="title<span class=" cls"="">"&gt;title<span class="cls"></span></a>
```

This hapens most likely because the same filter is used in both places.
How can I skip this title attribute change since they use the same filter?

> Note: I'm trying to do this inside a plugin I'm working on, so editing
>   the child theme won't be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that filter is used by the function [get_the_title][1], the filter only send 2 parameter the `title` and the `post_id` and this function is very used.

The best way to go is create a new function call it `get_the_title_with_span` and add your extra markup there, the change the `get_the_title` function for `get_the_title_with_span` where you want to add the extra markup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Enrique. I have edited my question to be more specific to my case. I forgot to add that I'm trying to do this inside a plugin I'm working on. Your solution implies editing the child theme's template so this is a NO GO in my case.